# Get File Upload Progress, when uploading files through AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I am uploading multiple files(videos and images), using ajax. I am not using a FORM.

I have seen resources mentioning the "session.upload_progress" directive. When I use a FORM, everything works fine.

But, I have a previously built system, that uploads files through AJAX and not forms(using drag and drop). Since the "session.upload_progress" requires a "session.upload_progress.name" directive to be hidden within the form and in the PHP file, "session.upload_progress.prefix" is referenced along with the form name, to get the progress of the upload, I am not sure how i could send the "session.upload_progress.name" directive to the uploading script.

Can someone guide me towards the correct way of doing this?

FYI, I am using PHP 5.4

Comment: If you are uploading files via ajax then you're using [`XHR2`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) which has an upload progress callback.

Comment: im actually using jquery to send the files to a php page and the php page is uploading them!